# For /f loop concatenate parameter

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

```bat
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
title Testing
color 4f

for /l %%x in (1,1,3) do (
  rem This is working
  set var1=%%x.extention
  echo !var1!
  for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (
      'wmic datafile where "name='C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe'" get version /value') do (
      ::This is NOT working. WHy??
      set var2=%%a.exention
      )

  echo !var2!

)

@pause
```

Can someone help me please? I'm trying to concatenate some variables, `for-loop` parameters and strings. Trouble is getting a string at the end of a loop parameter.
The string `.extention` in `set var2` is displayed with the `.extension` string first and not last as I want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the output of the [`wmic` command](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) is Unicode text and [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) has got problems with converting it to ANSI text, so some orphaned carriage-return characters are left, which let your output appear quite strange. You can prove this by redirecting the output of your batch script into a file and view it by a hex. editor.

To solve the problem, wrap around another `for /F` loop, like this:

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%b in ('
    wmic DataFile where "Name='C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe'" get Version /VALUE
') do for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ("%%b") do (
    echo(%%a.extension
)
```

N.B.:
Do not use `::`-style comment in blocks or loops as they may cause unexpected behaviour; use [`rem`](http://ss64.com/nt/rem.html) instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! This has annoyed me for days and weeks.
Work like a charm. And since "delims=" is default it can be dropped from the code

Comment: You're welcome! It's not thrue that `"delims="` is default, actually _space_ and _tab_ are the default delimiters; `"delims="` deactivates them...

Comment: @ebbie73 in this particular case you can remove delims= because the returned string from the command contains no space/tab but in the general case you should put it there otherwise it will return the string till the first space/tab only. Robust solution from aschipfl.